# Vim: Split Words Into Lines?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I frequently use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> in visual mode to **join** several selected lines into a single line with the original lines separated by spaces.  But I am wondering if there is an opposite shortcut such that it will **split** selected words into separate lines (one word per line).

Of course I can do:

`:'<,'>s/ /^M/g`

But something more succinct in terms of keystrokes would be very useful.  Has anyone else found a way to do this?

Thanks in advance,

-aj

Comment: could just map it to some shortcut...

Comment: If the cursor is positioned on a space that you want to replace with a newline, `s^M^[`.  `:call setline('.', split(getline('.')))` will split the current line by whitespace and explode it into multiple lines.  But neither of those does quite what you're asking for; for that, I can't think of anything better than what you have now, aside from maybe binding a shortcut as @michael and @Tristan suggest.

Comment: Related: `r<CR>` is a builtin 2 keystroke way to insert a linebreak in place of a whitespace char.   More sophisticated mappings like this await in [Insertlessly.vim](https://github.com/dahu/Insertlessly).

Comment: There is an old thread on the vim_use mailing list about this [here](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Opposite-of-lt-shift-gt-J-td1163281.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map it if you are using it often in your ~/.vimrc file or similar

```
vnoremap \ll :'<,'>s/ /^M/g<cr>
nnoremap \ll :s/ /^M/g<cr>
```

if you are only wanting to to it multiple times now you can use & command to repeat last search  also

Theres also gqq but thats for textwidth eg 80 chars

Comment: That should probably be `vnoremap` for visually selected words.

Comment: ahh true I hadn't noticed the <>

Answer (score 3):

Recently I stumbled across the same problem. My solution is the following vim function (put in my `.vimrc`):

```
function SplitToLines() range
  for lnum in range(a:lastline, a:firstline, -1)
    let words = split(getline(lnum))
    execute lnum . "delete"
    call append(lnum-1, words)
  endfor
endfunction
```

This can be used with line ranges, e.g., as follows

```
:26call SplitToLines()
```

which would split line number 26. But the code also handles ranges of lines gracefully (that's why the range in the for loop is built in reverse order).

```
1,10call SplitToLines()
```

will split lines 1 to 10 into several lines. However, I mostly use this in visual mode, like

```
'<,'>call SplitToLines()
```

which splits all lines that are visually marked. Of course you may define some single letter abbreviation for this function call (with auto completion by <kbd>Tab</kbd> I do not find it necessary). Also note that by adding an additional argument which would also be used by 'split' you can have a function that does split lines at specific patterns (instead of just white space).

Answer (score 2):

I use this in my config to Un-Join/split the last word on current line:

```
nnoremap <C-J> g_F<Space><Space>i<CR><Esc>k
```

It maps CTRL-j to do the opposite of  Join, I think of it as Counter-Join :) I mostly use it to convert between K&R style vs ...the other kind of curly brace placement.

```
g_       : search for the last non-whitespace on current line
F<Space> : reverse-find first space
<Space>  : go one character forward
i        : enter insert mode
<CR>     : insert a line break
<Esc>    : return to normal mode
k        : go up one line to where we begun
```